# Multiple hidden_field in one form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, hidden-field

Does ruby not allow two `hidden_field` in one form? The ranking value keeps saving as `3` even if a user changes it for challenges that have `date_started.present?`

If I take out `<%= f.hidden_field(:notes_date, value: date) %>` then the value saves correctly based upon user's selection, but of course I can't just take out that line because I need it to set the date.

**notes/form**

```
<%= form_for [@notable, @note] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :notes_text, placeholder: 'Enter Note' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:ranking, id: 'rank') %> # Defaults ranking to 3, but if user changes it in the form it still gets saved as 3 for date_started.present? challenges

  <% if @challenge.date_started.present? %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:notes_date, value: date) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.date_select :notes_date, :order => [:month, :day] %>
  <% end %>

  <%= image_tag('1.png', data: { ranking: 1 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('2.png', data: { ranking: 2 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('3.png', data: { ranking: 3 }, class: 'image-clicker clicked') %>
  <%= image_tag('4.png', data: { ranking: 4 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('.image-clicker').click(function() {
    $('#rank').val($(this).data('ranking'));
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
</script>
```

**Renders notes/form**

```
  <% if @challenge.date_started %>
    <% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged + @challenge.missed_days).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
      <% if @notes.any? { |note| note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") } %>
        <% @notes.each do |note| %>
          <% if note.notes_text.present? %>
            <% if note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
              <div class="notes-notes-background">
                <% if note.ranking == 1 %>
                  <%= image_tag '1.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
                <% elsif note.ranking == 2 %>
                  <%= image_tag '2.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
                <% elsif note.ranking == 3 %>
                  <%= image_tag '3.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
                <% elsif note.ranking == 4 %>
                  <%= image_tag '4.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
                <% end %>
                <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Day <%= i + 1 %></div>
                <b><%= note.notes_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></b><br><br>
                <%= link_to edit_note_path(note) do %>
                  <%= simple_format note.notes_text %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <div class="notes-form-background">
          <div style="margin-bottom: -23px; color: #a4a99f; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: #446CB3;">Day <%= i + 1 %></div><br>
          <div style="color: #a4a99f;"><%= date.strftime("%m/%d") %></div>
          <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %> # For date_started date is passed through to form
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
      <div class="notes-notes-background">
        <% if note.ranking == 1 %>
          <%= image_tag '1.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
        <% elsif note.ranking == 2 %>
          <%= image_tag '2.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
        <% elsif note.ranking == 3 %>
          <%= image_tag '3.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
        <% elsif note.ranking == 4 %>
          <%= image_tag '4.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
        <% end %>
        <b><%= note.notes_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></b><br><br>
        <%= link_to edit_note_path(note) do %>
          <%= simple_format note.notes_text %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="notes-form-background">
      <%= render "notes/form" %> # For nil date_started date is not passed to form
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Log**

```
# NOTE FOR CHALLENGE WITHOUT DATE_STARTED (AKA GOAL CHALLENGE)
# NOTE CORRECTLY SAVED RANKING

Started POST "/challenges/175-take-a-picture/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-11 14:34:39 -0400
Processing by NotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YYad25L/yIqbgnnWgD6ufHRBuAgQzc5kQZZ6TqvzNbDu2wQMnZ4yI2F8SdHoRLVBD/IOueXh6cJCGJFSVFoY5w==", "note"=>{"notes_text"=>"adfasdfasdf", "notes_date"=>"2016-05-08", "ranking"=>"1", "conceal"=>"0"}, "button"=>"", "challenge_id"=>"175-take-a-picture"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 78]]
  Challenge Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "challenges".* FROM "challenges" WHERE "challenges"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 175]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "notes" ("notes_text", "ranking", "notes_date", "user_id", "challenge_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["notes_text", "adfasdfasdf"], ["ranking", 1], ["notes_date", "2016-05-08 04:00:00.000000"], ["user_id", 78], ["challenge_id", 175], ["created_at", "2016-05-11 18:34:39.351527"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-11 18:34:39.351527"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "activities" ("action", "trackable_id", "trackable_type", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["action", "create"], ["trackable_id", 146], ["trackable_type", "Note"], ["user_id", 78], ["created_at", "2016-05-11 18:34:39.357991"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-11 18:34:39.357991"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/challenges/175-take-a-picture
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)

# NOTE FOR CHALLENGE WITH DATE_STARTED (AKA HABIT CHALLENGE)
# NOTE DID NOT SAVE RANKING

Started POST "/challenges/175-take-a-picture/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-11 14:38:05 -0400
Processing by NotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AmISZHocVRAxMgg50oiQZm4GT8m04uGJ2AH1iCE6jSeNP4uzdX2vucvMOD668otbFbX5eEHOxi/bjx6U3pOgcA==", "note"=>{"notes_text"=>"super sad face with 1 ranking", "notes_date"=>"2016-05-11", "ranking"=>"", "conceal"=>"0"}, "button"=>"", "challenge_id"=>"175-take-a-picture"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 78]]
  Challenge Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "challenges".* FROM "challenges" WHERE "challenges"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 175]]
   (3.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "notes" ("notes_text", "notes_date", "user_id", "challenge_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["notes_text", "super sad face with 1 ranking"], ["notes_date", "2016-05-11 04:00:00.000000"], ["user_id", 78], ["challenge_id", 175], ["created_at", "2016-05-11 18:38:05.365702"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-11 18:38:05.365702"]]
   (15.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "activities" ("action", "trackable_id", "trackable_type", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["action", "create"], ["trackable_id", 148], ["trackable_type", "Note"], ["user_id", 78], ["created_at", "2016-05-11 18:38:05.388367"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-11 18:38:05.388367"]]
   (16.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/challenges/175-take-a-picture
Completed 302 Found in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 39.3ms)
```

**HTML Output**

```
        <div class="notes-form-background">
          <div style="margin-bottom: -23px; color: #a4a99f; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: #446CB3;">Day 20</div><br>
          <div style="color: #a4a99f;">05/30</div>
          <form class="new_note" id="new_note" action="/challenges/176-meditate/notes" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="O1vx9h2yTuKmv6R/GyN8msppVp5iX+cMSIAbyWUsJKS0BmghEtO0S1xBlHhzWWensdrgL5dzwKpLDvDVmoUJ8w==" />

    <button name="button" type="submit" class="remove-note">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" id="challenge-name" placeholder="Enter Note" name="note[notes_text]">
</textarea>
    <div class="center">
          <input value="05-30" type="hidden" name="note[notes_date]" id="note_notes_date" />
    </div>
    <div class="emoticons-align-center">
      <span class="label label-primary" style="vertical-align: text-top;">How was it?</span>
      <input id="rank" type="hidden" name="note[ranking]" />
      <img data-ranking="1" class="image-clicker" src="/assets/1-d13146fa38dc5aa389b7136023e0a70d.png" alt="1" />
      <img data-ranking="2" class="image-clicker" src="/assets/2-e855957467934964a571061ed2f87edf.png" alt="2" />
      <img data-ranking="3" class="image-clicker" src="/assets/3-f39b8a225ddd8b1b9633c147ab4c605f.png" alt="3" />
      <img data-ranking="4" class="image-clicker" src="/assets/4-bc78072f299a492c5411b6e47cb85adf.png" alt="4" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <div style="float: left;">
        <input name="note[conceal]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input data-size="small" data-on-color="danger" data-on-text="Secret" data-off-text="Public" class="someclass" type="checkbox" value="1" name="note[conceal]" id="note_conceal" /> 
        <script>
          $("[class='someclass']").bootstrapSwitch();
        </script>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right;">
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn">
          Save
</button>      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  $('.image-clicker').click(function() {
    $('#rank').val($(this).data('ranking'));
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the log for this action with the notes_date hidden field included, specifically including the parameters and the activity that occurs during the action.

Comment: Updated question with logs @MichaelGaskill. Thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: It's clear that the ranking is sent as "".  The only thing that I see that could cause a problem is that the `value` for the 'notes_date' hidden field is `date`.  This would mean that you'd have to have a variable or method called `date` somewhere.  Do you know what it's value is?  Also, have you looked at the generated HTML to see if it looks right?  You might post that, as well, because it might show exactly what's happened.

Comment: Yea. I added where date comes from above the logs. It is from an iteration @MichaelGaskill of `<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged + @challenge.missed_days).each_with_index do |date, i| %>` and like sameera pointed out if I switch out images for text_field and then click save the :ranking will save. I don't know if you can tell the cause from that tidbit

Comment: I'm thinking that the issue is how `date` is output into the HTML.  Try changing the `:date => date` in the partial to `:date => date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` and see if that makes a difference.  Date is an object, so no telling how it's output in this case, but the strftime converts it into a string, and that's a well-understood value for a hidden field.

Comment: And I took out `value: 3` so it wouldn't conflict with `value: date`, but that made no difference @MichaelGaskill

Comment: Unfortunately @MichaelGaskill that didn't work :/

Comment: It was worth a try.  Can you post a snippet of the HTML from the browser with the hidden field issue happening?  You just need to 'View as Source' and find the right place, and copy the entire `<form>` section.  That way, we can see what's happening in the HTML itself.

Comment: Posted HTML output of form @MichaelGaskill. Maybe you see something I don't :)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill. I realize the behavior is if a note is created in consecutive order from the first note then the `:ranking` works, but if a user creates a note that is out of order then the `:ranking` doesn't save

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't have any exception as to allow only one hidden field for a form. You can have multiple. In my opinion, your problem lies somewhere else, maybe it's not setting the value to the hidden field as you expect.

To test this, make the hidden field as a normal text field and see if the value changes.

If that changes, then maybe do a break point in the controller and see what are you getting as params.

Comment: Thanks Sameera. Just updated question with logs and what is being passed through to it. I tested the `text_field` and if I manually type in the number and then click save then the `:ranking` saves so thank you for helping me further narrow down the problem :)